# use `mapActions` or `mapGetters` with Vuex 4 and Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Anybody knows how to use `mapState` or `mapGetters` with `Vue 3` in the `setup` function ?
I know that is possible to use the store with the `useStore` hook but with this hook We import all the store while with `mapState` or `mapGetters` we can specify a `module` :

```
// ...

computed: {
   ...mapGetters('myModule', [
      'myStateVariable'
   ]
) 

//...
```

Comment: `...mapGetters({myGetter: "myModule/myStateVariable"})` do you mean like this?

Comment: I want to use it with a module

Comment: @Ady642 Try this https://blog.codecourse.com/using-vuex-with-the-vue-composition-api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
import { computed }  from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const module = 'myModule';

export default {
    setup() {
        const store = useStore();

        return {
            // getter
            one: computed(() => store.getters[`${module}/myStateVariable`],

            // state
            two: computed(() => store.state[module].myStateVariable,
        };
    },
};
```

Comment: Yes that's work but you don't use any helper. For example to call an action you will need to use dispatch. That is what I was looking for `useActions` and `useGetters` : https://blog.codecourse.com/using-vuex-with-the-vue-composition-api/

Comment: @Ady642 Hopefully this will land soon: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1725

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, they get flattened so you can't use `myModule/myStateVariable`, but `myStateVariable` should work.

This could be something that may change as Vuex gets to RC releases, but for now if you try to have the same getter twice, you get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With vue 3 and vuex 4 I managed to do it like this:
suppose we have a store shown below:

[image]

our general store index.js (the one on the bottom) would be like this:

```
 import { createStore,     createLogger   } from 'vuex';
 import module1 from '@/store/module1';
 import module2 from '@/store/module2';


 export default createStore({

 modules: {
    module1: module1,
    module2: module2,
 },
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
  ? [createLogger()]
  : []
})
```

whereas the modules would each have such an index.js:

```
import * as getters from './getters'
import * as actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'


const state = {
  postId: 10111,
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
  
}
```

and the getter in each one of the module would be like this:

```
export const getPostId = state => {
   return state.postId 
}
```

finally in a component you could access the getters like that:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <div class="major_container">
     <p>{{ postIdFromModule1 }}</p>
     <p>{{ postIdFromModule2 }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<script> 
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
 setup() {
   const store = useStore();

   const postIdFromModule1 = computed(() => store.getters["module1/getPostId"]);
   const postIdFromModule2 = computed(() => store.getters["module2/getPostId"]);

   return {
     postIdFromModule1,
     postIdFromModule2,
   };
  },
};
</script>
```

Great, now you can use the modules namespaced!

Comment: yeah that's a correct answer but you don't use helpers. I create my own helpers to resolve this question : const { isTokenSet } = useAuthModuleHelpers();

Comment: you 're right, I just submitted the answer so that a whole moduled namespaced store configuration with vue 3 and vuex 4 would be online. I wasted many hours to get it running, and it would be nice to spare the next one from the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use `mapActions` in a vue3 style SFC is to use `mapActions` in the `setup()` function's `return`

```
import { mapActions } from "vuex"
setup() {
  return {
    ...mapActions("myModule", ["doSomething"])
  }
}
```